# new expandable listview highly customizable

Tags: android, listview, object, expandablelistview

I need to realize something like that in the picture:
[image]
"TITLE" rectangle makes a list of object and when I click on one of these objects is opened a "sub menu" (where there are ELEMENT #1, 2 etc.). The system is similar to a expandable listview, but more customizable.

How do you suggest to realize that?
How can i do an animation for the collapse of the sub menu? If I set sub menu with gone and then when onClick on title I set that with visibility=visible suddenly appears...I'd like something of animated in Android style.

What do you suggest? I was thinking to realize an object to istantiate each time i need to realize something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
                    CustomListViewDemo.java 

public class CustomListViewDemo extends ListActivity {
  private EfficientAdapter adap;

  private static String[] data = new String[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(adap);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Click-" + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  public static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Bitmap mIcon1;
    private Context context;
    int firstpos=0;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
      // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
      mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      ViewHolder holder;

      if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_content, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.sp = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        holder.ArrayAdapter_sp = new ArrayAdapter(parent.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,data);
        holder.ArrayAdapter_sp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        holder.sp.setAdapter( holder.ArrayAdapter_sp);
        holder.sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            private int pos = position;
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int p, long arg3) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Toast.makeText(context, "select spinner " + String.valueOf(pos)+" with value ID "+p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });




        convertView.setTag(holder);
      } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }


      return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder 
    {

        Spinner sp;
        ArrayAdapter ArrayAdapter_sp;

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return data[position];
    }

  }

}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        adaptor_content.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lineItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="314dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>


--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```