# Unable to capture the button click in a listview ? Please tell me why this code doesn't work

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview in my main activity which is followed by a textview. The list view contains buttons in it. When the button in the list is clicked i want some text to appear on the textatrea. But i am unable to capture the click of the button.

Following is the code i have used. Please tell me what is wrong. ( I don't want an alternative solution, but i want to know what is wrong in the code)

```
public class MyFirstAppActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {   
    ListView listview ;
    String[] array = new String[] {"Click1","Click2"};
    ArrayAdapter <String> arrayadapter;
    TextView textview;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.button,array);
        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
        listview.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>arg1,View v,int Position, long id){
        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textview.setText("Hello, you just clicked a button"+Position);      
    }
}
```

This sets the activity to main.xml as shown below. But when i click on the button in the list, the click is not captured. Why is this so ?

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ListView android:id="@+id/lv_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">        
            </ListView>

            <TextView android:id = "@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
                    android:layout_below = "@id/lv_1"
                    android:text="Message about the button is displayed here">        
            </TextView>"


        </RelativeLayout>
```

button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/button" >    
</Button>
```

Comment: check complete demo.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126536/new-expandable-listview-highly-customizable/12838389#12838389

Answer (score 1):

You're saying one thing and coding another...

`onItemClick` handles clicking on the row of your list, not the button.

In this case the button is stealing the click from the row, hence your onItemClick is not being called.

There are two options to fix this, depending on what you really want to be happening.

If you really want to click on the button itself and not the row, you need to override the `getView` method of the adapter and put in an `OnClickListener` for the button.

If you're happy just clicking on the row (which would look like clicking the button since that is the only thing in the row), you need to stop the button from stealing the clicks from the list row.  You can achieve that by setting `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` on the button in your xml.

Once you do that you are going to have an NPE...

There is no `R.id.textview` in your row layout, so the `onItemClick` will throw an NPE because your `findViewById` will return a null and then the setText fail.  You need to navigate from your clicked row to your parent layout and then find the textview (pretty much the same if you do it from the `getView` method too...

Assuming you stick with the `OnItemClick` method:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>arg1,View v,int Position, long id){ 
        ListView lv = (ListView) v.getParent();
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) lv.getParent();
        textview = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.textview); 
        textview.setText("Hello, you just clicked a button"+Position);       
    }
```

Comment: explaining how the buttons might be stealing the rowclick helped me solve an issue i was having. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in listview child xml.